# Windows 10 logging in to black screen

Tags: windows-10, laptop-repair, black-screen-of-death

A few days back, my laptop started doing something weird on (some) restarts. The laptop seems to turn on properly, I am able to log in using my username and pin, but when it logs in, all I see is a black screen. Entire taskbar is missing too. If I move my mouse around, it can be seen moving on the screen, and if I press the windows key, the start menu pops up, but that's just about it. Screen otherwise remains black.

Interestingly, if I try opening a program through the start menu, while I can't see it, it does seem to open although I can't see it. If I try switching programs using Alt+Tab, I see that program while I hold the keys down, but even if I "select" it, the screen remains black.

This seems to only be an issue on a restart, if it happened to open properly and I don't fully shut off the laptop (only lock it, etc.) then it stays working.

What I've tried so far:

Starting Windows in Safe Mode: I am able to get into Safe Mode, and everything works properly there. For a while, if I would restart after opening in Safe Mode, it would then boot normally, but now it doesn't work every time.
Rolling back Windows Updates: no luck.
Refreshing Windows but Keeping Files: The initial restart after Windows reinstalled worked, but shortly afterwards the error happened again.

My machine is about a decade old Dell Inspiron 15R-5521 running Windows 10 (had been for the most part up to date on Windows updates until this error started happening). It's been my workhorse, other than the battery failing after a while (got it replaced) and the screen having some blurry lines right when it turns on (due to the cold, I suspect. Goes away after a minute) it's been working well. Was hoping to keep it going strong another decade or more, maybe even until the next Epochalypse in 2038. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Next time it happens, try opening task manager (CTRL-ALT-DEL -> task manager) and restart explorer.exe or kill it, then file->run explorer. See if that works. It sounds like a windows update is the cause though, but lets see if the above trick helps you in that session first.

Comment: @LPChip No luck. I can open the task manager, but it seems to be "under" the screen (as in, I see it when I press Alt+Tab, but can't really interact with it directly).

Comment: okay, that does rule out a few things. Could be a driver issue but also a a graphics card going bad. There is a chance your laptop is dying and needs replacement.

Comment: Plug in an external monitor.  See what happens.  If you can get to the screen, try isolating the screen only to the second monitor.  What happens?